# Some Casbah functions not working

Tags: mongodb, casbah

In my project, I'm using Casbah and I reffered http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/tutorial.html tutorial. According to that I've implemented

```
     val mongoClient = MongoClient
     val db = mongoClient("db_name")
     val coll = db("coll_name")
     val a = MongoDBObject("hello" -> "world")
```

Then next step is **not** going to work.

```
coll.insert(a)
```

I'm using, `"org.mongodb"%% "casbah" % 2.7.0-RC0`

what is this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If running mongodb on localhost and the default port try changing:

```
val mongoClient = MongoClient()
```

So you call the apply method and return an instance of `MongoClient` not the object..

Answer (score 0):

```
MongoFactory.coll.save(a)
```

use save() to save MongoDBObject.